# Validating B2C JWT tokens in Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am using B2C to protect a WebApi in Asp.Net Core.  My code is below.   Do I need to validate the tokens or is the middleware doing it for me?  I would think if everyone had to do this, it'd be easier for me to find some sample code, but I can't seem to get any real direction on this.

Yet, this [B2C documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens) states that my api do the validation.

I found a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs) but it's not for Core and they're using `CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None`.  Doesn't that defeat the purpose?  And another [sample here](https://shellmonger.com/2017/03/02/azure-app-service-authentication-in-an-asp-net-core-application/) where they **are** doing it.

Don't I have to have the signing key from B2C and all that?

I can cobble together a solution from those, but do I actually need to do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = Constants.B2CAuthenticationSchemeName,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            MetadataAddress = string.Format(
                _identityConfig.B2CInfo.AadInstance,
                _identityConfig.B2CInfo.Tenant,
                _identityConfig.B2CInfo.Policies
                    .Where(p => p.IsDefaultSignUpSignInPolicy == true)
                    .First()
                    .Name),
            Audience = _identityConfig.B2CInfo.ClientId,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
            },
            Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = B2CAuthenticationFailed
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have the same question today. And I've been trying to validated in the API calls. I'm still thinking I have to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I need to validate the tokens or is the middleware doing it for me?

The JWT bearer middleware does it for you (by default, it will automatically reject unsigned or counterfeit tokens, so you don't need to explicitly set `RequireSignedTokens` to `true`).

> Doesn't that defeat the purpose?

There's a difference between validating a signature using a public asymmetric key (e.g RSA or ECDSA) embedded in a certificate and validating the certificate itself (and specially its chain). Signature validation is fully supported in ASP.NET Core, but certificate validation is not supported yet.

> Don't I have to have the signing key from B2C and all that?

The JWT bearer middleware automatically retrieves it from B2C's discovery endpoint, so there's no need to do that manually. For more information, don't hesitate to read the OIDC discovery specification: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html

Comment: I wish the rest of the documentation was as clear as your explanation.  Thank you so much!  And thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @nhwilly my pleasure (glad I could help!)